# Angularjs $resource and $http synchronous call?

Tags: json, angularjs, http, rest, asynchronous

I want write two services one with a `$http.get` method and one with `$resource`

This service should receive a Json Object and looks like this, at the moment this code is direct in my controller and not in a service:

```
 var csvPromise= $http.get(base_url + 'DataSource/1').success(function(data) {
     $scope.data4=JSON.stringify(data);
 });
```

The problem is, I want save received data in `$scope.data4` and I want use this data after the `$http.get` call but the value is empty.

Direct after this call there is and Object that needs this value:

```
new myObject($scope.data4)
```

so `myObject` must wait so long until the data has arrived.

or can I make a synchronous call with `$http` or `$resource` ?

How can i do this ? I  have found so many examples with `promise` and `.then` but nothing has worked for me.

EDIT: I have now written a service but it didn`t work:

```
 var test=angular.module('myApp.getCSV', ['ngResource']);
 test.factory('getCSV',function($log, $http,$q, $resource){
     return {
         getData: function (id) {
             var csvPromise= $http.get(base_url +'DataSource/'+id)
                 .success(function(data) {
                 return data;
             });
                 return csvPromise;
         }
     }
 });
```

and then in my controller I call this:

```
 getCSV.getData(1).then(function(theData){
         $scope.data4=JSON.stringify(theData);
         new myObject( $scope.data4); });
```

but this did not work. I thought if the `$http.get` receives the data then the `then` Function is called.

Comment: The `success` and `error` methods are `$http` specific and not do not form part of the promise chain. Change your service `getData()`  function body to just: `return $http.get(base_url +'DataSource/'+id);` This will return the promise and once resolved will call your `then` function inside your controller. See also my answer below for alternative options.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can do synchronous calls. That said, you have at least two options:

1) Pass in the data using the `$routeProvider` `resolve` feature. From the documentation:

`An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected`

An example on how to use this:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/your/path', {
    templateUrl: '/app/yourtemplate.html',
    controller: 'yourController',
    resolve: {
      data: ['$route', '$http', function($route, $http) {
        return $http.get(base_url +'DataSource/1');
      }]
    }
  })
```

And then in your controller:

```
app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', 'data', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.data4 = JSON.stringufy(data);
  var yourObj = new myObject($scope.data4);
}]);
```

2) The second option is to use promises and only instantiate your `new myObject($scope.data4)` once the promise successfully completes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be changed just a bit:

```
$scope.data4 = '';

var csvPromise= $http.get(base_url +'DataSource/1');
csvPromise.then(function(data){
    $scope.data4 = JSON.stringify(data);
}, function(data){
    //error handling should go here
    window.alert(data);
});
```

This should give you what it sounds to me like you need.

Comment: Can you give some specifics? Where did it fail? What errors were thrown?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, there's no way to `sync~` call the `http` or `resource`. They're hard coded on AngularJS core file :

```
xhr.open(method, url, true);
```

And you don't want to hurt your users too by blocking the browser wait the data arrived. You'll better show how you make the *nothing has worked for me* so we can start working to fix it.

Have you try call `new myObject($scope.data4)` inside `success` method?

```
$http.get(...).success(function(data){
    $scope.data4 = JSON.stringify(data); // I've no idea why do you need this.

    var stuff = new myObject($scope.data4); // THis is now your.
});
```